# Scala alternative cases match syntax with different type of extracted value

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, extractor

```
object NoSense {
   def main(args: Array[String]) {
      val value = "true" match {
         case value @ (IntValue(_) | BooleanValue(_)) => value
      }
      require(value == true)
   }
}

class Value[T](val regex: Regex, convent: String => T) {
   def unapply(value: String): Option[T] = value match {
      case regex(value, _*) => Some(convent(value))
      case _ => None
   }
}
object IntValue extends Value[Int]("[0-9]+".r, _.toInt)
object BooleanValue extends Value[Boolean]("((true)|(false))".r, _.toBoolean)
```

The `require` in the `main` method will fail.

but this one is ok

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
      val value = "true" match {
         case IntValue(value) => value
         case BooleanValue(value) => value
      }
      require(value == true)
   }
```

Is that the limitation of scala language itself or i am doing in a wrong way

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's... both.

You may take a look how at how the pattern binder behave in the [Scala specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) §8.1.3. It says that in pattern `x@p`:

> The type of the variable x is the static type T of the pattern p.

In your case, the pattern `p` is `IntValue(_) | BooleanValue(_)`. As `IntValue` and `BooleanValue` unapply-methods both require a String, the static type of your pattern is `String`, thus, the type of `x`is `String`.

In the second case, value is extracted from BooleanValue and have the right type.

Unfortunately, scala does not support alternatives of extractors patterns, thus you must stick to your second version.

Comment: For my use case, is there any better solution? I feel that i am using extractor in a wrong way?

Comment: No your usage of extractor here is correct. But your match is not exhaustive. Furthermore the inferred type of value is Any, it may be unappropriate, depending of the context.